# How to see if a tx was private using web3.eth.getTransaction?

Tags: web3js, flashbots, private-transaction

If a tx is sent to miners directly (e.g.: using flashbots) instead of the public mempool, etherscan lists these transactions as 'private transaction'.

How would I check if a tx is private using `web3.eth.getTransaction` or similar?

Comment: You can't do it by querying a node. Etherscan is able to do it cause it checks if the transaction was present in his mempool, but a normal node doesn't keep track of that.

Comment: Check if the `to` field of the transaction is not the recipient, but the address of the miner or any intermediary contract to allow privacy.

Answer (score 1):

**You can't.**

Etherscan achieves this by ordering all the transactions within that block by the gas price, if the order of the transaction (by index) does not match the order by the gas price (descending), the block contains private transactions.

And you could know the transactions that do not match the order are sent from private RPCs.