# How to see if a transaction was private?

Tags: txpool, flashbots, private-transaction

Is it possible to check if a transaction was sent privately (e.g. via flashbots , bloxroute) or using the public mempool? If yes, what would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Etherscan achieves this by ordering all the transactions within that block by the gas price, if the order of the transaction (by index) does not match the order by the gas price (descending), the block contains private transactions.

And you could know the transactions that do not match the order are sent from private RPCs.

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/134223/126666